# JUnit test user input with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a problem with the Mocking Framework Mockito. I want to test the input the user types in the console. Without Mocking it works great but with it I don't know how to get the return value from the function which get's the input in the console.

**Without Mockito:**

Read input method

```
public int readUserInput() {
    BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    return Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
    ...
}
```

Test method:

```
public class TestClass {
    Controller contr = new Controller();
    @Test
    public void testUserInput() {
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes()));
        assertEquals(1, contr.readUserInput());
        System.setIn(System.in);
    }
}
```

But now how to write the test with Mockito. I tried several ways but none of them worked. I got all the time a 0 and not the number I wrote in the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Mock `BufferedReader`'s   `readLine()` API to return your value.
i.e

```
 Mockito.when(mockedBufferedReader.readLine())
                .thenReturn("1");
```

Now when you call the readInput() from the Test then your mocked buffered reader's API will be invoked.Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks but can you please give me more code to understand your way of doing it.

Comment: you do @Mock BufferedReader mockedBufferedReader; //this will mock your BufferedReader and inside your test case you mock the API using the above lines of code.

Comment: or brush up Mockito knowledge with this tutorial :http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextFromStandardInputStream` rule of the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) library instead of Mockito. It ensures that `System.in` is always resetted after the test. (Your code doesn't reset `System.in` in case of a failing assert.)

```
public class TestClass {
  @Rule
  public TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();

  Controller contr = new Controller();

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    systemInMock.provideText("1");
    assertEquals(1, contr.readUserInput());
  }
}
```